# Java import com.sun.prism.Graphics

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGbIG.png)Does anyone know, how to solve the `import com.sun.prism.Graphics` problem? It says to me, that the import is not accessible.- I coded this according to the tutorial... And Java also advices me to add this command. But when I add it, Java says that its not accessible.

(Basic game tutorial)

Comment: `com.sun` in internal. Don't use.

Comment: what tutorial was that?

Comment: Basic Java Game turorial. Im just beggining.  
Andreas Java.awt.Graphics has worked. Thank you very much. And can I ask you, what was the problem?

Comment: *"Basic Java Game turorial."* Provide a link to it! Tip: Add @Simons0n (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. *"what was the problem?"* The problem is that those classes in the `com.sun` package hierarchy are *'subject to change without notice'* and should not be used directly. Any tutorial which uses them is ***highly suspect*** and itself, should not be used.

Answer (score 1):

This is internal class of particular JRE implementation. It is not part of Java Language Soecification. The tutorial you are using is bad in this sense.

If you really want to implement graphics with Java, consider Java FX.

Comment: Java FX? Well Because I ve started just few days ago, I am not really sure what to do. I wanted to learn begins and then start codding android apps.. Im still not sure yet.  But thanks for advice!

Comment: @Miky537: If you plan to work on Android apps, then Java FX is not the best choice. I'd suggest you search for an Android tutorial and start with it. Sorry I don't want to discourage you. But if you start from the right thing now, you will save much time :)

Comment: Im grateful for every advice. Ive tried many possiblities. (and it seems, ill try another one :D) Thanks for help!